# Unity 3D How to check if a gameobject remained in the same position every x amount of time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is the code I managed to come up with, the output isn't consistent.  I assume it has something to do with the code not being looped properly.  Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong please?

The issue seems to be after X seconds have passed, it will continually check positions without waiting for the time to pass.

```
IEnumerator checkPosition()
{       
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(X);
        newpos = this.gameObject.transform.position;
        //Debug.Log(newpos);

        if (oldpos == newpos)
        {
           Debug.Log("Player remained idle");
        }else if (oldpos != newpos)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player moved");
        }

        oldpos = newpos;
    }
}   

void Start()
{
    oldpos = this.gameObject.transform.position;
}                                                                         
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(checkPosition());                                         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks object's position only once after `X` amount of time. You need to loop your check routine.

```
IEnumerator checkPosition()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(X);
        newpos = this.gameObject.transform.position;
        //Debug.Log(newpos);

        if (oldpos == newpos)
        {
           Debug.Log("Player remained idle");
        }else if (oldpos != newpos)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player moved");
        }

        oldpos = newpos;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
You need to start your coroutine in `Start`. The `Update` method is executed every frame. So you start the coroutine without waiting for the `X` amount of time. When you start your coroutine in `Start`, it will be executed only once and will run pseudo-parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I implemented the while loop but it is still giving me the same issue, I have updated the description to the further detail the issue.

Comment: Ok I saw your update, I moved the StartCoroutine to the Start method and it solved everything. Thank you and good day!